# Multidimensional linear arrays C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was reading this article: [How to loop through multi-dimensional arrays quickly](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/06/c_c_tip_how_loop_through_multi_dimensional_arrays_quickly).

I would like to know more about "linear multidimensional arrays" but I can't find anything of relevance and would like to know if any of you have seen anything like it.

Specifically I would like to understand better how to access a multidimensional array (that's declared as single dimension) using math. It sounds awesome!

Comment: In order to make the question easier to read/answer, it would be appreciated for you to [edit] and make sure to include the desired behavior and the specific problem and error that you are facing as the [help/on-topic] guidelines show.  Thank you!

Comment: That web page doesn't load for me. But if it explains how to do it, what more do you need to know?

Comment: You need to ask specific questions. "I would like to understand better" is very vague and broad.

Comment: Suppose you want an P x Q x R matrix of `double` values.  You could use `double matrix[P][Q][R];` or you could use `double matrix[P * Q * R];` — the latter is what the article means by a 'linear multidimensional array'.  They each have some advantages; they each have some disadvantages.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks I'm starting to see more clearly the linear multidimensional arrays the article talks about. I guess since the way data is stored is linear, all multidimensional arrays are linear arrays. I could also mention that the article is referring to different ways of iterating this arrays, I just didn't realize that there were more than one way for iterating through the array.

Comment: @Barmar Allow me to rephrase: How do I use math for accessing an array instead of the "loop inside of loop" approach?

Comment: There are lots of ways of doing it. Note that there are column-major and row-major orders (C uses one, Fortran the other). You can also have fun accessing a 4x7 sub-array in the middle of a 50x60 array.

Comment: @DanielBernal The website you linked to answers the question: `value = data[ i * height * depth + j * depth + k ];`. What more do you need to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Statically allocate

In c, if you want to create a 3x4 array for example you need to do like following code:

```
int array1[3][4]; // statically allocate 3x4 integer in stack. The memory will be organize like this:
// [[0, 1, 2, 3] // first row
//  [4, 5, 6, 7] // second row
//  [8, 9, 10, 11]
```

It would be the same if you declare a 12 int array

```
int array2[12]; // memory will be
// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

So: `array1[2][3] == array[2* (number of columns) + 3] = 11`

Both are the same, the first one is easier to read than the second one. The compiler knows the dimension of the array, so it will calculate the address for you.

## Dynamically allocate

In this case you don't know the dimension of the array, so. Create a 3x4 array will like this

```
int **array1 = (int **) malloc(rows * sizeof(int *)); // allocate 4 pointers
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  array1[i] = (int *) malloc(columns * sizeof(int)); // allocate memory for each row.
}

// the memory will be organized like this
// array1 [row0pointer, row1pointer, row2pointer]
// some where else in the memory: ... row0 ... row1 ... row2 ..
```

It's not optimize because you need memory to store pointers, and when you access each member you have to access through pointers.
So you can allocate a single array that has rows * columns member instead:

```
int *array2 = (int *) malloc(rows * columns * sizeof(int));

// then when you want to access array2[i][j] you can easily access 
array2[i * columns + j]
```

The same with n-dimensions array.

Comment: 3rd option: `int (*array3)[columns] = malloc(sizeof(int[rows][columns]));`